# Python чтение qr code

Tags: python, python-3.x, qrcode

Есть ли возможность, чтения(сканирования) QR кодов без библиотеки zbar?
Спасибо.

Comment: Да, есть такая возможность

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как

Comment: Ну, библиотекой [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/de/dc3/classcv_1_1QRCodeDetector.html), например.

Comment: да, но она не все читает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [PyQRCode](http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/)

Пример использования

```
import sys, qrcode
d = qrcode.Decoder()
if d.decode('out.png'):
    print 'result: ' + d.result
else:
    print 'error: ' + d.error
```

Comment: декодер на яве...

Comment: Спасибо.Но AttributeError: module 'qrcode' has no attribute 'Decoder'